# How do you know what your minimum case to variable ratio should be using any given method?

Tags: regression, logistic, spss

I am trying to self-teach statistical analysis, and only have my class stats notes from six years ago to help me try and figure this out. I have written down that for Forward Likelihood Ratio method, the minimum is 25:1 and the preferred is 40:1 but I don't have any source on this and don't know why it's true. I also have no information on other methods. Is there a method to work this out or a text that lays it all out?